# Matlab wont quit using the cross sign in the waitbar when there is an out of bound exception for the image

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

The value for the columns is 51 and 50, but when we use anything more than that the waitbar freezes due to index out of bound exception since its a large image and it wont fit in there, so the matlab dosent shut using the waitbar or anything. Need a way to shut the matlab when it encounters any error.

```
h = waitbar(0,'Progress','Name','Calculating Feature Heights...',...
        'CreateCancelBtn','setappdata(gcbf,''canceling'',1)');
setappdata(h,'canceling',0); %initiallizes waitbar
s1 = size(A);
s2 = size(B);

if (s1(1) < s2(1))
    n = s1(1);
else
    n = s2(1);    % ensures that bounds of i are within the bounds of both images
end
for i = 21:1:n    % sets bounds for rows

if getappdata(h,'canceling')    %checks for user pushing the cancel button on the waitbar
    break
end
waitbar(i/(n-1),h)     %progress bar
    for j = 61:1:(m-60)    % sets bounds for columns
        if A(i,j) == A(i,j-1)   %if adjacent pixels are the same, 
            Z(i,j) = Z(i,j-1);  %they have the same height
            disp(i,j) = disp(i,j-l);
        elseif A((i), j) == B(i, j) && A(i,j) ~= A(i,j-1) && A(i,j-1) == B(i,j-1)
            Z(i,j) = Z0;    %condiions for pixels/features in the 'focal plane'
            disp(i,j) = 0;
        else
            for l = 1:1:20  %sets scan range in rows for disparity
                for k = 1:1:60   %sets disparity scan range in cols
                    if (A(i,j) == B(i-l, j-k) && B(i-l, j-k-1) == B(i-l, j-k))
                        Z(i,j) = Z(i-l,(j-k-1)); %allows for multipixel features
                        disp(i,j) = disp(i-l,(j-k-1));
                        break
                    elseif (A(i, j) == B(i-l, j-k) && B(i-l, j-k-1) ~= B(i-l, j-k))
                        xA = [i j];
                        xB = [i-l j-k];
                        d = xB-xA;
                        Z(i,j) = Z0 - (fl*shift)/sqrt((d(1)^2)+(d(2)^2));
                        disp(i,j) = sqrt((d(1)^2)+(d(2)^2));
                       break
                    elseif (A(i,j) == B(i-l, j+k) && B(i-l, j+k-1) == B(i-l, j+k))
                        Z(i,j) = Z(i-l,(j+k-1));
                        disp(i,j) = disp(i-l,(j+k-1));
                        break
                    elseif (A(i, j) == B(i-l, j+k) && B(i-l, j+k-1) ~= B(i-l, j+k))
                        xA = [i j];
                        xB = [i-l j+k];
                        d = xB-xA; 
                        Z(i,j) = Z0 - (fl*shift)/sqrt((d(1)^2)+(d(2)^2));
                        disp(i,j) = sqrt((d(1)^2)+(d(2)^2));
                        break

                    else
                        continue
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end 
delete(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`try`/`catch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) block.

```
try
   % whatever that might error
catch
    delete(h)
end
```

Comment: This is the error "for j = 61:1:(m-60)" when I exceed the value more then 51:50 it freezes and dosen't unfreeze by whatever means. So need to get rid of this issue

Comment: @CLearner  With a try catch block **around the for loop** there is no issue.  Try it.